# Powershell how to stop progressbar

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to read data from an array and displaying a progressbar.
My goal is to stop the loop and progressbar and to do this I did it this way.

```
function ButtonStart_Click {

     $LabelCounter.visible = $true
     $ProgressBar1.Visible = $true
     $ButtonStart.Enabled = $false
     $ButtonStop.Enabled = $true
     $script:CancelLoop = $false

     # =============================================================
     # LOOP EXCEL DATA OBJECT
     # =============================================================
     $Counter = 0
     $ErrorCounter = 0;

     foreach ($Row in $ExcelData) {

        if($script:CancelLoop -eq $true){
           $progressbar1.Value = 0
           break;
        }

        $Counter++ 
        [Int]$Percentage = ($Counter/$ExcelData.Count)*100 
        $ProgressBar1.Value = $Percentage 
        $LabelCounter.Text = "Show $Counter of " +$ExcelData.Count
        [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents() 
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 900

     }

     $ButtonStop.Enabled = $false
}

function ButtonStop_Click {
    $ProgressBar1.Value = 0
    $script:CancelLoop = $true
}
```

Unfortunately it does not work because after the loop has started, I try to click the stop button (even if it is enabled) nothing happens until the end of the loop.
In the past I used do-until for start-stop a progressbar but without read a array and it worked well.

```
function ButtonStart_Click {

    $LabelCounter.visible = $true
    $ProgressBar1.Visible = $true
    $TextBoxSubject.ReadOnly = $true

    $Progressbar1.Maximum = 100

    $script:CancelLoop = $false
    $ButtonStop.Enabled = $true
    $this.Enabled = $false
    $Progressbar1.Value = 0

    do{

       if($script:CancelLoop -eq $true){
          $progressbar1.Value = 0
          break;
       }
       $Progressbar1.PerformStep()
       [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
       sleep -Milliseconds 900

    }
    until($Progressbar1.Value -eq $Progressbar1.Maximum)

    $this.Enabled = $true
    $ButtonStop.Enabled = $false

 }
```

I do not understand where I'm wrong.
How could I do?
Thank you

Comment: Is this for WPF? I was trying to reproduce it to debug.

Comment: @TylerSzabo - Is for WinForms